# How to do grid interpolation interp2 in OpenCV

Tags: matlab, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to figure out how to do the equivalent of this matlab code in OpenCV, A few places to use `cv::remap` as an alternative to `interp2`, but it is giving me different results than matlab.

In case it helps this is inside of a function that is performing a piecewise-affine transform, as part of fitting an Active Appearance Model.

```
    [XI, YI] = meshgrid(1:img_Col, 1:img_Row);
    imNew=zeros(nRow,nCol,nChannels);
    for i=1:nChannels
        imNew(:,:,i) = interp2(XI, YI, double(img(:,:,i)),Ix(: , :),Iy(: , :));
    end
```

`img_Col` and `img_Row` are just the size of `img` I've also included what sample values of `Ix`, `Iy`, `img`, and `imNew` (after the code has run) in [this](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8BdK_BSCn9RfjNDRWQ0S3ZUdkhGZEM1dGFqZmhlOGxVZ3VyU19hZzRVc011X0l2RGsyU2M&usp=sharing) Google Drive folder (I only bothered to include the first channel of the images). I've seen it mentioned on a few other questions that `remap` only works on a regular grid, which frankly I don't exactly know what that means (those questions are [cv::remap (in opencv) and interp2 (matlab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912234/cvremap-in-opencv-and-interp2-matlab) and [remap irregular to regular grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403774/remap-irregular-to-regular-grid).

These images demonstrate what the goal is to make. https://i.stack.imgur.com/w91ZZ.jpg

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: `cv::remap` defines a mapping between source and target.  You are providing which pixel to sample from the source image where it should appear in the target image.... so that won't work in your case.  What you really want is to resize the image (I think) and so `cv::remap` is not an option here.  BTW, which environment are you using?  You specified OpenCV, but I don't know if you're using the C++, Python or Java wrappers.

Comment: I'm using the C++ wrapper

Comment: Are you trying to resize the image?  What does `Ix` and `Iy` contain?

Comment: OpenCV is in C++... No wrapper.. :D

Comment: As rayryeng already mentioned, you should be ok with cv::resize, with paramerer INTER_LINEAR

Comment: I don't `cv::resize` will quite work, I added a link to what the original image and the output are.

Comment: I'm trying to write something similar to http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.PiecewiseAffineTransform.estimate in OpenCV

Comment: can you post a working code in Matlab that I can copy and run, and obtain your result? (I cannot probably test it for a few days, but could be useful also to others)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to do:

```
remap(img, imgNew, Ix, Iy, CV_INTER_LINEAR);
```

Seriously, I tested it and it gives identical results to your MATLAB code (and the images you attached).

The 'irregular' grid people are mentioning refer to the sample points grid (`XI` and `YI` in your case). While in MATLAB these are allowed arbitrary values on the image, in OpenCV these **have** to be simply the grid of pixels in the target image (`imgNew` in your case):

```
XI = 1 2 ... n   YI = 1 1 ... 1
     1 2 ... n        2 2 ... 2
     ...              ...
     1 2 ... n        m m ... m
```

This is why in OpenCV you do not even pass the `remap` function the `XI` and `YI` matrices since `Ix` and `Iy` are assumed to correspond to the sample points above.

Luckily you calculated your `Ix` and `Iy` matrices accordingly so it works just out of the box.

This is all due to the fact that `remap` is implemented by something like:

```
for x <- 1...n
  for y <- 1...m
     imgNew(x,y) = interpolate the value of img at the point (Ix(x,y), Iy(x,y))
  end
end
```

As mentioned in the `remap` [theory](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/remap/remap.html) and [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=remap#remap).

Comment: Sorry I do not get here the difference between XI, YI and Ix and Iy.
I have a similar problem, where:

    im_warp(:,:,c) = interp2(im(:,:,c), XXdense, YYdense,'*linear');

@stav I want to convert it to C++, I already have 2 mats in OpenCV with the same values as XXdense, YYdense... But the output when I plug in remap is completely different.. What do I do to calculate the Ix and Iy... and what are they...?

Comment: Since you're calling `interp2` without `X` and `Y` you don't need to calculate those in C++ either. Basically your case seems identical to the OP's so there is something else wrong. Feel free to post a minimal sample of the problem both in MATLAB and C++ and I'll try to help.

Comment: I tested Interp2 in matlab and remap in OpenCV but they behavior differently. I am curious how you get the identical results @Stav

Comment: Check my post here   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692060/matlab-interp2-function-behaviour-dfiferently-compared-with-opencv-remap